# Update Tire index without using Tire::Model::Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I've gone over the Tire documentation and I understand that it's possible to create indexes and import objects into Elasticsearch using Tire without using the ActiveModel includes.

I would like to keep my model files completely clear of any Tire mappings and rather implement them separately.

So far I've created an indexing object for my Member model like this:

```
class MemberIndexer
  def initialize(member)
    @member = member
  end

  def attributes
    {
      id: @member.id,
      name: @member.full_name,
      age: @member.age,
      birthday: @member.birthday,
      type: 'member'
    }.to_json
  end

  def self.refresh_index
    Tire.index 'members' do
      delete
      create mappings: {
        member: {
          properties: {
            id: { type: 'integer' },
            name: { type: 'string', boost: 5 },
            age: { type: 'integer' },
            birthday: { type: 'date' }
          }
        }
      }

      Member.find_in_batches do |members|
        import members.map { |m| MemberIndexer.new(m).attributes }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine and the index is created and I can search properly. What I'm missing are callbacks that can be included by using `Tire::Model::Callbacks`. Is it possible to update individual records in the index using tire without needing to include `Tire::Model::Callbacks` in the model itself?

For example, if I update a `Member` I want to manually be able to update the corresponding item in the members index. Is this possible without knowing the `_id` for that item?

Should I just do a search for the object using the ActiveRecord id and then use the update method on the index?

**UPDATE:**
I was confused by the fact that ES was indexing the members not with the actual ActiveRecord id but by generating a unique id in ES even thought I was passing an id in the attributes json.

When I passed a ruby hash into the `import` method the id field was respected and this problem went away as I can now just do the following to update an index record:

```
Tire.index('member') do
  store(MemberIndexer.new(@member).attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The [update callback](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/callbacks.rb) is nothing more than the following code

```
after_save do
  update_index
end
```

So if you were to call @member.update_index from somewhere it will update the index for that record.

Comment: Seeing as I have not included the Tire modules in my Member class there is no `update_index` method on `@member`. In the end though the problem was submitting json to the `import` method.

Comment: Or, even better - only updating if our indexed fields change: updated_index if changed & %w(name email deleted real_name)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about not knowing the `_id`, from the code you posted, it's the `@member.id`, right?

But you can implement it something like this:

```
def update_es_index!
  Tire.index 'members' do
    store(@member)
  end
end
```

It will call the [store method](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L120) which will figure out which URL to post to.

Comment: For some reason when I was converting the attributes to json the bulk `import` method was not respecting the id of the Member object, but instead was generating a unique id in ES. Once I submitted a ruby hash to the `import` method everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was some sort of mistranslation when converting the Ruby hash to JSON.

When I passed a Ruby hash to the `import` method the index records were created with the appropriate ActiveRecord id and therefore I'm able to just call `store` with the attributes that include the ActiveRecord id when I want to update the index.